# SQL CLR - retrieving data / updating results

Tags: sql, sqlclr

As part of my business logic I have to retrieve 2000+ rows from a sql table.  Run those rows through some complex, procedural, business logic (yes it has to be procedural, and all running sum techiques I research so far don't cut it for efficiency).  Then I have to update the database, and return the results.

Using SQLDataReader - the data is streamed out of SQL, and into my logic - which works just fine.

The logic iterates over the data, and makes the necessary changes.

Now to save the changes - I really don't want to sent the result over by filling parameters to an UPDATE statement.  If I had the results over in SQL, I would join the temp table with the base table, and perform all the updates in a single TSQL Update statement.  By my "table" is in SQL CLR, and the base table is over on the SQL side.

I've read the techniques about serializing out the results to XML, and transfer it all over with in a varchar variable - but I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I've looked at UDT, and Table Value Parameters - but you can't use those to transfer data between SQL CLR and SQL.

If SQL CLR is suppose to be used with complex business logic - isn't there a best practise means of sending the data over?  I have not found an example yet that directly addresses or talks to this issue.

Comment: I thought SQL CLR was designed to be put in a DLL and run from within the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update all your columns at once, in various records in a single call to the database you are right to use XML.
Below a sample of the query you could use.

```
if OBJECT_ID('sample1') is not null
drop table sample1
go
create table sample1(id int identity(1,1), firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100))
go

declare @xmldata xml
set @xmldata  = 
N'<sample>
        <data>
            <firstname>Jay</firstname>
            <lastname>Keni</lastname>
        </data>
        <data>
            <firstname>Lid</firstname>
            <lastname>kurtis</lastname>
        </data>
        <data>
            <firstname>Lea</firstname>
            <lastname>Cortez</lastname>
        </data>
</sample>'


declare @xml_hndl int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @xml_hndl OUTPUT, @xmldata

insert sample1(firstname, lastname)
select up.firstname, up.lastname
FROM OPENXML(@xml_hndl, '/sample/data',2)
WITH  (firstname varchar(100),lastname varchar(100))up

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @xml_hndl

select * from sample1
```

you can do Updates, inserts, delete, with any join operation you want, this code will work from SQL server 2005 to denali.

Comment: Have you thought of using FileStream in 2008 to stream the results from SQL CLR into a FileStream object.  Then use another stored procedure to retrieve the FileStream and (somehow) create a TVF to retrieve the binary results in rows?

I like the XML, but it seems very verbose, especially with large results.